JSON Query - 'jq' how do I get / update an object from an array or list
I have the below code in which I need to get/update the values of an object. I am able to get jq -r .settings.tasks What I need is to get and update values of base_parameters under notebook_task and it's objects project/path using jq utility.
"settings": {
   "tasks": [

      {

        "email_notifications": {},

        "job_cluster_key":"artifactory_download_job_cluster",

        "max_retries":0,

        "min_retry_interval_millis":900000,

        "notebook_task": {

          "base_parameters": {

            "project":"app1",

            "path":"dir1/source1/file



to get the property project (for example) of any object in the tasks array: jq -r '.settings.tasks[].notebook_task.base_parameters.project' ... but to better address your question, do you need to change its value with the same exact string for any target found? And do you need to modify the json file itself or just output the new json?

To access notebook_task -  since tasks is an array you can use array[] syntax:
jq '.settings.tasks[].notebook_task' yourfile.json

or
jq '.settings.tasks[].notebook_task.base_parameters' yourfile.json

if you want to update a value inside it's the same idea
jq '.settings.tasks[].notebook_task.base_parameters.project = "app2"' yourfile.json

